# Decrypting AES/CTR video while watching

Tags: encryption, video-streaming, aes, ctr-mode

It is possible to decrypt an encrypted video in AES/CTR and and watching as it was being decrypted?

I want to decrypt Video hosted on MEGA.co.nz and go watching as that goes down without waiting for the download to complete.

I already know how to decrypt, just need to know how to do this gradually in a video

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. Most video formats and codecs can be decoded in a streaming fashion. For example: MPEG4. AES in CTR mode can be decrypted as a stream.

Comment: Do you have any examples of how to do this in C # or other linguaguem?

Comment: No, I don't and this would be too broad for a StackOverflow answer.

Comment: I'm using BouncyCastle he do it?I know how to do it using?

Comment: I found this file https://github.com/sybil-sink/mega-sdk/blob/master/MegaApi/Crypto/Crypto.cs but do not know how to adapt to BouncyCastle